# How to display individual options by knowing the full option type

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a sample database below:

Question Table:

```
QuestionId (PK auto)  QuestionNo   OptionId (FK)
11                     1             1
12                     2             3
13                     3             26
```

Option Table

```
OptionId  OptionType
1         A-C
2         A-D
3         A-E
4         A-F

...

25        True or False
26        Yes or No
```

Now below I have displayed each question number and their recognised option typea:

```
 foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

    ?>

    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key]); ?></p>

    <?php

}

?>
```

So the output looks like this:

```
1: A-C
2: A-E
3: Yes or No
```

But what I want to do is also display each indivdual option now by determining the full option type. For example if the option type is `A-C`, then it should display `A B C`, if option type is `A-E` display `A B C D E`, if option type is `Yes or No`, then display `Yes No`.

Each indivdual option should be displayed as a checkbox. So if you have `A B C`, then it should be:

A (checkbox)
B (checkbox)
C (checkbox)

My question is how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a combination of explode and increment operator on characters. For example:

```
<?php

$questions = array(
  array(1, "A-E"),
  array(2, "Yes or No"),
  array(3, "A-C"),
  array(4, "True or False")
);

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    echo $question[0] , ': ' , ExpandOptionType($question[1]), '<br/>';
}

function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
  $options = explode('-', $option);
  if(count($options) > 1) {
    $start = array_shift($options);
    $end = array_shift($options);
    do {
      $options[] = $start;
    }while(++$start <= $end);
  }
  else{
    $options = explode(' or ', $option);
  }
  return implode(" ", $options);
}

?>
```

Output:

```
1: A B C D E
2: Yes No
3: A B C
4: True False
```